# Don't allow users to deselect variation swatch in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

On our website for our brand [Keylight](https://key-light.nl/product/air-max/) we use the plugin Variation Swatches and Photos to let the customer select different variant options via color and image swatches. Every product has a default selection set up with the 'select option' option disabled for the variant selection. The customer is unfortunately still able to 'deselect' a chosen swatch by pressing it again which leads to confusion since that results in an invalid variation. The customer should always select one option for each attribute.

We searched on Google for a solution but the closest we got is with this post [Don't allow users to deselect variation in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50410325/dont-allow-users-to-deselect-variation-in-woocommerce). We applied this piece of code which does remove the selection in the dropdown option selection, but that doesn't work with swatches since you can still deselect a swatch.

What we want is when a customer presses a swatch for a second time, it doesn't unselect the swatch so that there always is a variation chosen. Does anybody know how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following jquery you can detect if user clicks on already selected option which will make it unselected and prevent unselecting it.
For that, place the following in a js file that is loaded on the product or create file and load it in your theme, or use plugin like "Simple Custom CSS and JS" or any other plugin out there.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.select-option.swatch-wrapper').on('click', function(e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
});
```

Updated code. Its abit overkill with checks but let me know if this works.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($('.select-option.swatch-wrapper').length > 0 ) { 
            $('.select-option.swatch-wrapper').on('click', function(e) {
                if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice creative answer. You should add this code to a function hooked in  `woocommerce_after_variations_form` for example.

Comment: We tried the j Query code in the footer and it does work properly, but that creates errors outside the product pages. Then we tried to add it to the woocommerce_after_variations_form, but that doesn't work yet. Could you elaborate a little further on how to add this properly? This is the code we used:
<code>
function woocommerce_after_variations_form(){ ?>
  <script>jQuery(function($) {
  $('.select-option.swatch-wrapper').on('click', function(e) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
          e.stopPropagation();
      }
      });
  });
</script>
<?php }
</code>

Comment: I cant tell how this swatches plugin works but maybe try with different hook like woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form

Comment: We found our mistakes and it now works correctly. Thank you both for you support!

Comment: I have added update on the code if you feel like trying it. But if its works the original one its also fine. Glad you found what was the issue.